# Squeryl Select Duplicates

Tags: sql, scala, squeryl

I would like to find overlapping data with a Squeryl query. I can do so by using the method found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519582/how-to-select-non-unique-rows) with normal SQL, but can't figure out how to do so using Squeryl.

Basically I need to convert this line that finds Non-Distinct rows to Squeryl

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable L1 
JOIN(
  SELECT myField1,myField2 
  FROM myTable 
  GROUP BY myField1,myField2 
  HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
) L2 
ON L1.myField1 = L2.myField1 AND L1.myField2 = L2.myField2;
```

**EDIT :** More importantly I need to be able to do this dynamically. I have a bit of a complex dynamic query that I call that may rely on different options being passed. If an Option is defined then it should call this, otherwise inhibit if null. But groupBy does not support an inhibitBy method. To see a full explanation of my current method [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17222246/squeryl-dynamic-join-clauses)

```
def getAllJoined(
  hasFallback:Option[String] = None
  showDuplicates:Option[String] = None):List[(Type1,Type2)] = transaction{
  join(mainTable,
    table2,
    table3,
    table3,
    table4.leftOuter,
    table4.leftOuter,
    table5,
    table6)((main, attr1, attr2, attr3, attr4, attr5, attr6, attr7) =>
    where(
      main.fallBack.isNotNull.inhibitWhen(!hasFallback.isDefined)
    )
    //What to do here to only find duplicates when showDuplicates.isDefined? AKA Non-Distinct
    select(main,attr1,attr2,attr3,attr4,attr5,attr6,attr7)
    on(
      (main.attr1Col === attr1.id) ,
      (main.attr2Col === attr2.id) ,
      (main.attr3Col === attr3.id) ,
      (main.attr4Col === attr4.map(_.id)) ,
      (main.attr5Col === attr5.map(_.id)) ,
      (main.attr6Col === attr6.id) ,
      (main.attr7Col === attr7.id)
      )
  ).toList
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/squeryl/FNbiH2ng5b0) discussion on Google Groups. Looks like they had fixed a bug related to inhibited having in 2011, but not sure why it still persists in your case. They also have an example query using the having clause in the same thread.

Comment: I stumbled upon that a while ago as well, but I just realized I didn't give enough detail in my question. I also need to be able to inhibit this entire check. Question updated with more detail.